# Will IBM MobileFirst provide a validation I'd after app authenticity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have two questions here which will be dependent on each other.

1. what happens after app authenticity and if its successful will the server send back a validation I'd to app. ?

   If app gets the validation I'd .
2. I want to send it to my web server and on each call I want to send this validation I'd to adapter level to check if the validation I'd is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. what happens after app authenticity and if its successful will the app send back a validation I'd to app. ?

Please review the authenticity tutorial, which explains how authenticity works: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

Authenticity check is done on the application. Not on the adapter.
The check happens at the first time the application attempts to connect to the server. If it fails you will no longer be able to run the app again unless it is removed and re-installed.

> 2. I want to send it to my web server and on each call I want to send this validation I'd to adapter level to check if the validation I'd is valid.

Per my explanation above, this is irrelevant.